# How to reset a value to its original state if changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I change an inputs value and want to reset it back to the original value onClick of a link how can I accomplish that?

I can use .data() to grab and store the original value but I am not sure of the best way to restore it if needed.

HTML:

```
<input class="someClassName" type="text" value="100" /> 
<a href="#">Edit</a>
<a href="#">Reset</a>
```

This is how I think it would work...

In the HTML above, the input will be rendered with a value of "100". If I then click "edit" I can use .date() to store the original value (100). I can then change the value of the input but if I wanted to reset the value back it's original state I would need to call the .data() info and use it to restore the value of the input.

How would I do that using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `.data` is perfect for that. look no further

**update - with some code directions**

Assuming you want to have this done for many input fields and not just one I am assuming each input+edit+reset are contained in a single parent

```
<div>    
    <input class="someClassName" type="text" value="100" /> 
    <a class="EditLink" href="#">Edit</a>
    <a class="ResetLink" href="#">Reset</a>
</div>
```

and in your init script block

```
$(".EditLink").click(
             function() {
                $(this).parent().children("INPUT").data("val",
                  $(this).parent().children("INPUT").val());
             });
$(".ResetLink").click(
             function() {
                $(this).parent().children("INPUT").val(
                  $(this).parent().children("INPUT").data("val"));
             });
```

I didn't test it but it should work

Comment: That's what I thought but I am looking for help with the code.

Comment: You are correct about having many of these on one page. It works, http://jsfiddle.net/hPQ3w/ Should I do anything with .removeData()?

Comment: You don't really have to, but it can be nice to clean up the data when you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend giving your input an id then reference that.

```
<input class="someClassName" id="theInput" type="text" value="100" /> 
<a href="#" id="Edit">Edit</a>
<a href="#" id="Reset">Reset</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function{
            $("#Edit").click(function{
                   $("#theInput").data('originalValue',$("#theInput").val());
                   });
            $("#Reset").click(function{
                   $("#theInput").val($("#theInput").data('originalValue'));                       
                   });
         });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Tom. This works but I need the variation that Variant did because there will be multipul of these on a page.